# Drawer Navigation contents

Tags: react-native, expo, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, react-navigation-drawer

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhYSM.jpg)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhDSd.jpg)
Hello guys, I've just started learning React Native and encountered some difficulties. I want to create a three-dot icon below the avatar and email as shown in the picture. Previously, I was using React Native Expo and installed React Navigation. What should I add to make the icon display a submenu within the drawer content? Can anyone help me?

I want to create a three-dot icon below the avatar and email as shown in the picture. Previously, I was using React Native Expo and installed React Navigation. What should I add to make the icon display a submenu within the drawer content? Can anyone help me?